# In Gradle, how to specify testnames from testng-context xml while using useTestNg

Tags: gradle, testng

I am using existing testng-context xml in build gradle

```
test {
useTestNG() {       
    suites 'src/test/resources/testng-context.xml'
    setTestName 'smoke1'
}
```

In my testng-context xml, I have different group of tests like smoke1, smoke2:

```
<test name="smoke1">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="smoke" />
        </run>
    </groups>
    <packages>
        <package name="com.servicestesting.tests" />
    </packages>
</test>
<test name="smoke2">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="smoke" />
        </run>
    </groups>
    <packages>
        <package name="com.uitesting.tests" />
    </packages>
</test>
```

How do I provide this custom tests in my gradle test task?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to run your test according to the name like smoke1 or smoke2.

May be you should create a new Gradle Task command in your build.gradle file like this:

```
    task smokeTests(type: Test) { 
   useTestNG() {
       useDefaultListeners = true
       suites 'src/test/resources/testng-context.xml'
       includeGroups 'smoke1' 
   }
}
```

Then use gradle smokeTests command to run your tests.
Here's a more detailed article about it.
https://www.swtestacademy.com/how-to-use-testng-with-gradle/